# iOS, change UIContainerView's child view from within child

Tags: objective-c, uicontainerview

I am trying to re-create fragment style navigation in cocoa touch.
I have previously done something similar with android (using activities in a fragment style).

Currently i have a ViewController, which holds 1 UIContainerView, with 4 UIImageViews. Naturally, selection of a specific image view determines the content of the container.

What i wish for now is on touch of a button, within the container view's child would trigger a change in content (child view). The Parent view controller would stay the same, only the container views content would change.

When i was developing in java for android i would pass the application context (`getApplication()`) to activities/classes so i could interact between activities.

**How would i go about achieving this in iOS?**

What i assume i am looking for is a way to pass the reference of the parent view's container view to successfully `addSubView:` from within the subview

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach. That's the parent who is expected to manage children. It's ofc possible to do, but I consider it as a bad convention and bad practice. Are you sure you need to do it like you've said?

Comment: I started with the project using standard segues between activity's, however design alteration now requires fragment style. this is what i could come up with to appease both the overall design, as well as existing code without too much change. ideally, it would be done differently. do you have any suggestions of methods?

Comment: I'm afraid that depends on your code. If you need to modify something from the child, you can always write self.parentViewController.view etc. However it's really a bad practice and one day when someone reads the code you won't be proud of your code. I'd add gesture handling on parent, handle change there instead of child.